# Convert all text document inside a directory to html document - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pdf, operating-system

I have a close to 10000 text documents which I need to convert/save it into .html and convert it to pdf using python.

I tried a package called 'texttohtml'

which can be installed using

```
pip install texttohtml
```

from terminal:

```
python -m texttohtml.convert C:\Users\User\Downloads\AAPL -o C:\Users\User\Downloads\AAPL_pdfs
```

It did not work. I ran twice still it did not give me any errors or did it create any html documents.

[image]

Comment: You have not explained if you had any problems using the texttohtml library? If you had, then share the errors you are getting.

Comment: @Cow I have edited it. The texttohtml did not give me any output. Thanks

Comment: But according to the documentation you can only convert one file at a time and you are giving it a whole folder. Their example `python -m texttohtml.convert elaa.txt -o elaa.html` You use directories. https://github.com/elaa0505/TexttoHtml
Maybe you should look into looping over all the files in the directory and then convert them while looping?

Comment: @Cow, could you please help me how to loop through all text files and convert them into html files.

Comment: @Cow could you please help me looping through all text documents insde a directory and converting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

def change_file_extension(old_extension, new_extension):
    # Get a list of all files in the current directory
    files = os.listdir()

    # Iterate through the files and rename those with the old extension to the new extension
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(old_extension):
            new_name = file.replace(old_extension, new_extension)
            os.rename(file, new_name)
            print(f"Renamed {file} to {new_name}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    old_extension = ".txt"
    new_extension = ".html"
    change_file_extension(old_extension, new_extension)
```

This worked for me to convert to html. I need to further work on converting each html document to pdf

Answer (score 0):

I take no responsibility for any lost data.

This should run through your directory and try to convert every file:

```
import os, subprocess

from_directory = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\AAPL"
to_directory = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\AAPL_pdfs"

for file in os.listdir(from_directory):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(from_directory, file)):
        try:
            subprocess.run(f"python -m texttohtml.convert {os.path.join(from_directory, file)} -o {os.path.join(to_directory, file.split('.')[0]+'.html')}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to convert file: {file} Error: {e}")
            if "No data" in e: print(f"File: {file} was empty.")
```

-o means, that on success, instead of writing to stdout, it will write to a file.

I suggest you test it before trying it on all the files.

Also, this will only convert to HTML files and not PDF.